# Objective-c : action:@selector(xxxxxx) not called

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, selector

I'm currently trying to add a button to my app. If the user push on it, it should display an alert.

I want to add the button to a section header of a `tableview.` Here is my code in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

```
UIImageView *headerView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)] autorelease];
...
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 4, 15, 15)];
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg"];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showMyAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[headerView addSubview:button];
return headerView;
```

And in the same class, I have the method :

```
-(void)showMyAlert{
    NSLog(@"HERE SHOW ALERT");
    ...
}
```

The button is correctly displayed but the `showMyAlert` method is never called when I push on it. 
Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong with my code ?
Thanks if you could help me :)

Comment: Is button highlighed when you push it?

Comment: Are you sure your headerview is presented with button?

Comment: try using @selector(showMyAlert:) and also update your method to -(void)showMyAlert:(id)sender

Comment: No, the button is not highlighted. Should it be ?

Comment: I tried using selector(showMyAlert:) and (id)sender but it still doesn't work.

Comment: karthika : yes, I am sure that I can see the button in my headerView :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `UIImageView` as `UIView` and return it as the header view.

```
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)] autorelease];
```

Comment: Great! It works!
I just had to change one more line, because I'm using an image as header background :
`[headerView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader"]];`
makes the app crashing, so I used :
 `[headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader.png"]]];`
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure img is not nil. If that is nil, your button will have no image and you will see nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joride. But the image is displayed (myimg) is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Modified below lines of code, Try like this:-

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showMyAlert:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)showMyAlert:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"HERE SHOW ALERT");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in viewDidLoad,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)] autorelease];
[headerView addSubview:imageView];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 4, 15, 15)];
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg"];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showMyAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[headerView addSubview:button];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but didn't get more success